# How to create aws lambda with Spring after SpringBootRequestHandler became deprecated?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services

I try to research aws lambda with Spring boot.
I found a lot of tutorials with `SpringBootRequestHandler` implementation, but nowadays this library is counted as deprecated. So I try to find a solution and found one: https://codetinkering.com/spring-boot-request-handler-deprecated/. This solution declares to use the `@SpringBootApplication` class for lambdas definition, so I created a very simple project that saves and received data to/from DynamoDB:

```java
package com.example;

@SpringBootApplication

public class DynamoDbApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DynamoDbApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private LinkService service;

    @Bean
    public Function<String, Link> getLink() {
        return (url) -> service.getUrl(url);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<UrlLongRequest, String> saveLink() {
        return (request) -> service.saveLink(request).getLongUrl();
    }
}
```

But I do not understand how to add these functions into lambda in the AWS console. All tutorials say I have to determine the class that implements `SpringBootRequestHandler`:

[image]

In this case (in the tutorial), `OrderHandler` class implemented mentioned interface `SpringBootRequestHandler`, but as we know - this interface is deprecated already and I do not use it. So which path do I have to put for the AWS console? When I tried to set my `DynamoDbApplication` class I received an error during lambda testing:

[image]

How to correctly implement a serverless solution with Java Spring?

Answer (score 1):

you can also refer to this [documentation on spring was lambda](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-function/docs/3.0.14.RELEASE/reference/html/aws.html#_getting_started)
you can try something like this,

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class FuncApplication implements ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FunctionalSpringApplication.run(FuncApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private LinkService service;

    @Bean
    public Function<String, Link> getLink() {
        return (url) -> service.getUrl(url);
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<UrlLongRequest, String> saveLink() {
        return (request) -> service.saveLink(request).getLongUrl();
    }

    public Function<Foo, Bar> function() {
        return value -> new Bar(value.uppercase()));
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext context) {
        context.registerBean("function", FunctionRegistration.class,
            () -> new FunctionRegistration<Function<Foo, Bar>>(function())
                .type(FunctionType.from(Foo.class).to(Bar.class).getType()));
    }

}
```